# How to extract in a text file only the needed data and save it to csv using php

Tags: php, csv, text

I was given a text file that contains more than a hundred of rows with 6 columns but the data that i need are on column 3 and 6 and save it to a csv file. The text file contains like this:

```
00001   1   01408156                33  0   2014/11/17  15:21:18
00002   1   00000007                33  0   2014/11/17  15:39:59
00003   1   01409179                33  0   2014/11/18  07:39:45
00004   1   01410352                33  0   2014/11/18  07:40:07
00005   1   01404048                33  0   2014/11/18  07:40:12
00006   1   01411402                33  0   2014/11/18  07:40:30
00007   1   01409227                33  0   2014/11/18  07:40:34
00008   1   01410323                33  0   2014/11/18  07:40:43
00009   1   01409242                33  0   2014/11/18  07:40:46
00010   1   01010042                33  0   2014/11/18  07:40:49
00011   1   01409192                33  0   2014/11/18  07:40:53
00012   1   01409192                33  0   2014/11/18  07:40:56
00013   1   01409171                33  0   2014/11/18  07:41:21
00014   1   01403005                33  0   2014/11/18  07:41:34
00015   1   01010205                33  0   2014/11/18  07:42:00
00016   1   01411465                33  0   2014/11/18  07:42:07
00017   1   01411381                33  0   2014/11/18  07:42:13
00018   1   01403018                33  0   2014/11/18  07:42:20
00019   1   01411447                33  0   2014/11/18  07:42:24
00020   1   01410308                33  0   2014/11/18  07:42:31
00021   1   01411381                33  0   2014/11/18  07:42:36
00022   1   01411427                33  0   2014/11/18  07:43:15
00023   1   01404029                33  0   2014/11/18  07:43:28
00024   1   01411452                33  0   2014/11/18  07:43:58
00025   1   01404061                33  0   2014/11/18  07:44:07
00026   1   01409278                33  0   2014/11/18  07:44:11
00027   1   01409266                33  0   2014/11/18  07:44:17
00028   1   01404113                33  0   2014/11/18  07:44:21
```

By the way the text file came from a biometrics thumb print machine that records the following data above. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried this code but when i try to extract the necessary data i am getting an offset error:

```
if (file_exists($myFile))
{
 $fileContent = file($myFile);

 foreach($fileContent as $line_num => $line) {
 { 
   $data = explode(", ", $line);

   $fileUsername[] = trim($data[0]);
   $filePassword[] = trim($data[1]);
 }
}
```

This is the code that i successfully extract the data that i need but i want to explode the last column to separate date from time:

```
$file=fopen("D:/Documents/My Documents/GLG_001_12215C.txt","r");

$i=0;

$line=array();
while(($data=fgetcsv($file,1000,"\t"))!==FALSE){
if($i>0){
$data[0]="";
$data[1]="";
$data[3]="";
$data[4]="";
$data[5]="";

unset($data[0],$data[1],$data[3],$data[4],$data[5]);
$line[]=$data;
} 
$i++;
//print_r(array_values($data));

}

fclose($file);
//array_shift($line);

$converted=fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/HRMS/temprec.txt","w");

foreach($line as $li){
fputcsv($converted,$li);
//print_r(array_values($li));
}
fclose($converted);

echo "import successful";
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post some code and show us what you've tried, to help us help you. you shouldn't need PHP for this, perhaps you could use a bash script?

Comment: I am new to php and I have tried to convert it to array but i can't extract the data that i need and i can't save it to a csv file.

Comment: Edit your answer with the code you have used so far. Trying to convert the text to an array is a good start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the source data contain a heading?  According to your sample post the file is comma delimited, is that right?  If yes, then I would use PHP to read the sample file and create an array.  Something like this:

```
$file = fopen('sample_file.csv', 'r');
$fields = array();
if($file)
{
 while(($data=fgetcsv($file, ',')) !== false)
 {
  if(empty($fields))
  {
   $fields = $data;
   continue;
  }
  $output[] = array_combine($fields, $data);
 }
 fclose($file);

// After the above code runs you will have an array named $output that contains all the data from the source file.
// Then you just use a loop to read the array and extract the columns you want and write them to a file.
// The loop would look something like this:

 foreach($output as $main)
 {
  echo("$main['Heading1'], $main['Heading2'], $main['Heading3']");
 }
}
```

Instead of an echo command you would need to write code to write the data into a file.

**EDIT - New program:**

Here is a new program to try.  Since you agreed with me that there were 7 columns this version will work.  However, PHP date and time usually have a space between the date and time and not a tab.  If there is a space and not a tab then this version will have to be tweaked a little.

```
if(!$myfile = fopen("data.txt", "r"))
{
 echo("Unable to open data file!");
 exit;
}
while(!feof($myfile))
{
 $line = explode("\t", fgets($myfile));
 $write[] = $line[2] . "\t" . $line[5] . "\t" . $line[6];
}
fclose($myfile);
if(!$handle = fopen("temp.csv", "w"))
{
 echo("Can't open file for writing!");
 exit;
}
foreach($write as $line)
{
 if(fwrite($handle, $line) === FALSE)
 {
  echo("Can't write to file!");
  exit;
 }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Enjoy!

**2nd EDIT:**

Ok, just replace this line of code:

```
 $write[] = $line[2] . "\t" . $line[5] . "\t" . $line[6];
```

with these 2 lines of code:

```
 $dt = explode(" ", $line[5]);
 $write[] = $line[2] . "\t" . $dt[0] . "\t" . $dt[1];
```

**EDIT - Final version**

Ok, based on the fact that there is 1 tab between each column except for 3 tabs between 01408156 and 33 this works for me.

```
if(!$myfile = fopen("data.txt", "r"))
{
 echo("Unable to open data file!");
 exit;
}
// The below line is to read the headers and discard
$line = feof($myfile);
while(!feof($myfile))
{
 $line = explode("\t", fgets($myfile));
 $dt = explode(" ", $line[7]);
 $write[] = $line[2] . "\t" . $dt[0] . "\t" . $dt[1];
}
fclose($myfile);
if(!$handle = fopen("temp.csv", "w"))
{
 echo("Can't open file for writing!");
 exit;
}
foreach($write as $line)
{
 if(fwrite($handle, $line) === FALSE)
 {
  echo("Can't write to file!");
  exit;
 }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Let me know how it goes.

**Last EDIT**

I added headers to my sample and found I made a mistake.  This line of code:

```
$line = feof($myfile);
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
$line = fgets($myfile);
```

Unless, you want the 3 headers in your output file

**New Final Version**

Here is a version that doesn't use array to build the output data.  This version will read the input and write the output all at once.

```
if(!$input = fopen("data.txt", "r"))
{
 echo("Unable to open data file!");
 exit;
}
if(!$output = fopen("temp.csv", "w"))
{
 echo("Can't open file for writing!");
 exit;
}
// The below line is to read the headers and discard
$line = fgets($input);
while(!feof($input))
{
 $line = explode("\t", fgets($input));
 $dt = explode(" ", $line[7]);
 if(fwrite($output, $line[2] . "\t" . $dt[0] . "\t" . $dt[1]) === FALSE)
 {
  echo("Can't write to file!");
  exit;
 }
}
fclose($input);
fclose($output);
```

Let me know how it works.

Comment: I guess my code did not help?  I could help you better if you supplied an exact sample of the data you are reading.  And what 2 fields are you trying to extract and write to the new file?

Comment: check my new post. I only need the data from the third column and the datetime in the last column and separate the date from time before saving it in a csv file but I am stuck after saving it to csv.

Comment: How do you get your data?  Your original post showed some data but it appears to not be comma or tab delimited and no headings.  I see 7 columns of data, is that correct?  The more details you provide the better I can help.  If possible post the first 10 lines of sample data, exactly the way you get it.

Comment: Ok, check out my answer above for a new program version.  If it works for you then please accept the post as your answer.  If you need to tweak the program for date and time then let me know.

Comment: Ok i will try your code but I also need to separated date from time so that in csv i can save three data namely the IDs which is in column 2, date that is extracted from datetime and time that comes from datetime also. Thank you

Comment: I posted some code for you to update.  See my 2nd edit above.  Don't forget to change the file name to read from and write to.  Let me know how it goes.  If you want me to explain anything just ask.

Comment: should i unset the array so that it will not be offset?

Comment: I tested the code before I posted it and I didn't get any errors.  I get the correct output file with 3 columns and a tab in between each column.  I used your sample data and replaced the spaces with tabs.  Let me ask you a question.  There seems to be a lot of space between 01408156 and 33.  Are you sure there is only 1 tab there.  Or is there 2 tabs?  Please check your source file and let me know.

Comment: I checked and the other fields of data have multiple tabs. I edited your code and add unset and delete the data inside the indexes that where unused but my problem now is I am having offset in the line of $write[] = $line[2] . "\t" . $dt[0] . "\t" . $dt[1];. Thank you

Comment: should i use array_combine first in that line?

Comment: the original text files have headers but i can erase it by using array_shift

Comment: I need to know exactly how many tabs are between each column.  I assumed 1 tab between each column and a space between the date and time columns.  If there are more tabs then the code will have to be tweaked a little more.  Let me know the exact number of tabs between each column of data.

Comment: I just saw your new post.  You say the original text files have headers.  Can you post a sample file somewhere?  On your web site for me to download?  Or some file sharing site?

Comment: only in between the 01408156 and 33 have 3 tabs.

Comment: http://www.uploadedit.com/_upload-documents-checkstatus.htm?new_name=1440828559543.TXT

Comment: I posted a New Final Version of the code.  See above.  Also, I think the reason you got an offset error is because of the header line in the file.  If this version doesn't work then upload your data file and provide me a link to it.

Comment: Thank you for helping a newbie like me I appreciate it much. It will also help others that are having problems same as mine.